# Rewriting ARRAY_PAYLOAD instruction

Tags: smali

I'm trying to find a way to rewrite immediates that are used in array initialization.

For example, this Java code:

```
package my;

public class Test {
    public static final int[] SomeArray = { 10, 20, 30 };
}
```

produces the following smali (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
# direct methods
.method static constructor <clinit>()V
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 4
    const/4 v0, 0x3

    new-array v0, v0, [I

    fill-array-data v0, :array_0

    sput-object v0, Lmy/Test;->SomeArray:[I

    return-void

    nop

    :array_0
    .array-data 4
        0xa
        0x14
        0x1e
    .end array-data
.end method
```

I'd like to change the immediate values to 100, 200, 300 (appropriately).

The `array-data` element has a `ARRAY_PAYLOAD` opcode and represented in smali as an instance of `DexBackedArrayPayload` class. [Instruction rewriter filters instances](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/rewriter/InstructionRewriter.java#L54) of `ReferenceInstruction`, and since `DexBackedArrayPayload` is not instance of `ReferenceInstruction` - there's no out-of-the-box support.

I thought to create (and return) new instance of `DexBackedArrayPayload`, but as its name describes - to retrieve array elements it reads directly from dex file.

Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Update: I found a workaround - instead of returning `DexBackedArrayPayload`, I'm returning an instance of anonymous class that implements the [ArrayPayload](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/76d69c7466b74b79e492d0edc6ff619adaeb78a1/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/iface/instruction/formats/ArrayPayload.java) interface.

Comment: Though, I'm still interested to see if there's another (perhaps, more elegant) way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the general idea of the rewriting stuff you're looking at is that you provide your own subclasses for the things you're interested in, and override the rewrite method to do.. whatever it is you're wanting to do.

In this case, it sounds like you want to create and return a new ImmutableArrayDataPayload with your own numeric constants.